# Comparing two matrix and took the value if match the criteria

Tags: matlab, matrix, compare

I have some question. I have 2 matrix, it's have same size.
For example, first matrix :
1

1

0

0

1

0

Second matrix 
34

56

12

12

33

14

Then, I want to compare this two matrix and groups it by the criteria on first matrix
so I will have this two groups matrix :
Matrix when the first matrix is have value 1

34

56

33

and 
Matrix when the first matrix is have value 0

12

12

14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
a = [1 1 0 0 1 0]';
b = [34 56 12 12 33 14]';

b(a==1)
b(a==0)
```